# .load() When loaded page change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my problem - i have Div with include "file.php" with content of Database then i Insert new data to database and want to reload .load() file.php to div but content is same until i refresh the page. Someone who know what it is ?
File.php

```
<?php
include "../lib/dbconnect.php";
$class = $_GET['class'];
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT content, date, author, author_id FROM classPosts WHERE class = '$class' ORDER BY id DESC");
while (list($content, $time, $author, $author_id) = mysql_fetch_row($get_posts)){
    $get_user_name = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastName FROM users WHERE nick = '$author'");
    while (list($name, $lastName) = mysql_fetch_row($get_user_name)){
        $time = new Cokidoo_DateTime("@" . $time);
        echo "
            <div class=\"div\">
            <div class=crop-small title=\"$author\">
                <a href=/user/user.php?user=$author_id><img src=/user/pics/$author_id.jpg class=img-small></a>
            </div>
            <span class=small-text><b style=\"color: rgb(100,100,100)\">$name $lastName</b><br>
            <span class=\"small-text\">Přezdívka <b style=\"color: rgb(100,100,100)\">$author</b></span><br>
            Přidáno $time</span><p><br></p>
            <span class=\"small-text\">$content</span>
            </div>
        ";
    }
}
```

?>

there is Javascript

```
 if(data.success)
            {
                $("#class_posts").fadeOut(function(){
                   $("#new_post").hide(0);
                 $("#class_posts").load("../trida/get_posts.php");
                   $("#class_posts").fadeIn();
                   $("#new_post_text").html("");
                });
            }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `data` from? does it have a success parameter?

Comment: Yes, its $.Ajax JSON Form and it works

Comment: The only reason I ask is because you mentioned `.load` which doesn't support JSON and your php doesn't seem to be returning json, based on what you posted above.

Comment: Ah, I see. The `?_=" + $.now()` should work, but it's the same thing as the rand num solution in ahren's answer.

Comment: Your database query is **extremely** open to SQL injection. Please please please read up on SQL injection, how to prevent it and consider moving to prepared statements with PDO. **Do not** release this code. Please.

Answer (score 2):

try appending a random number on the end as a query string - to prevent caching.

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
$("#class_posts").load("../trida/get_posts.php?"+randNum);
```